# Plotly graph plot using pandas/polars df taking long time >10 secs when working with 10k row & 15 cols. Please suggest how to improve performance

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit, python-polars

Using the below code was trying to plot pandas dataframe bargraph, it works quite fast when volume of data is less in input excel file but if data is more, say around 10k with around 15-20 columns then the graph plot is taking quite a lot of time (around 9-11 secs). We are in process of using 4-5 different type of graphs (pie, histogram, treemap etc) in our set of code and we are expecting this way the overall completion time for all type of graph plots will be much more.

Below is the code snippet we are using:

---

```
barGraph_df = final_df.groupby(by = columns[0], as_index = False)[columns[1]].sum()   
fig = px.bar(barGraph_df, x = columns[0], y = columns[1], color=columns[0], template = "plotly")  
                st.write("### :bar_chart: Based on X-Axis =" ,"'",columns[0],"'" ,"and Y-Axis =", "'",columns[1],"'")
                st.plotly_chart(fig,use_container_width=True, height = 200)
```

---

Note: Here columns[0] and columns[1] we are taking from user input and these are among the columns present in main input excel file.

---

We have tried with polars dataframe also with the below code, but not seeing much improvement:

---

```
barGraph_df = final_df.group_by(columns[0]).agg(pl.col(columns[1]).sum())
fig= px.bar(x=barGraph_df[columns[0]], y=barGraph_df[columns[1]], color=barGraph_df[columns[0]], template="plotly") 
st.write("### :bar_chart: Based on X-Axis =" ,"'",columns[0],"'" ,"and Y-Axis =", "'",columns[1],"'")
                st.plotly_chart(fig,use_container_width=True, height = 200)
```

---

Can anyone advise how we can improve the performance here?

Our approach we have mentioned in details above. We are expecting to improve the performance of data parsing.

Comment: Hi Kunal, welcome to SO. Do you mind to have a look at [ask] and [mcve]? It will be great if you can format your question,

Comment: I think that putting the data in cache would improve the speed. See [this](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching).